Space after display math mode
In TeXbook in answer to exercise 14.30 it is said:

Nothing follows the display, since a blank space is ignored after a closing $$.

But where in TeXbook the rule, that a blank space is ignored after a closing $$, is actually stated?
This is exercise 14.30:

Guess what happens if you say \noindent$$...$$ \par.


The TeX gurus will be here any minute to give a proper answer, but after a closing $$, I suppose TeX enters vertical mode? And it doesn’t enter horizontal mode again until it detects a non-space token? I think the answer is something along those lines.

good question:-)

@DavidCarlisle I found the rule on p. 293

Unlike after a command, the space character is not ignored, runs of space characters are scanned as usual and make a space token.
TeX has returned to horizontal mode after the display so normally a space token would make a space.
There is however one <optional space> token after the $$ that ends a display, the space token is gobbled if it is seen.
This is only explicitly mentioned in the TeXBook in the answer that you quote, but in tex.web you see
@ @<Declare act...@>=
procedure resume_after_display;
begin if cur_group<>math_shift_group then confusion("display");
@:this can't happen display}{\quad display@>
unsave; prev_graf:=prev_graf+3;
push_nest; mode:=hmode; space_factor:=1000; set_cur_lang; clang:=cur_lang;
prev_graf:=(norm_min(left_hyphen_min)*@'100+norm_min(right_hyphen_min))
             *@'200000+cur_lang;
@<Scan an optional space@>;
if nest_ptr=1 then build_page;
end;

where the @<Scan an optional space@>; gobbles this space.
@<Scan an optional space@>; is the code used to ignore spaces after numbers or units in dimens and several other places, for example
@<Scan units and set |cur_val| to $x\cdot(|cur_val|+f/2^{16})$, where there
  are |x| sp per unit; |goto attach_sign| if the units are internal@>;
@<Scan an optional space@>;
attach_sign: if arith_error or(abs(cur_val)>=@'10000000000) then
  @<Report that this dimension is out of range@>;
if negative then negate(cur_val);
end


My first reaction to your question was “it's stated in the answer to exercise 14.30”. But the rule can be inferred also from other places.
You should read pages 188–189, where the math display process is described.
For instance, \noindent$$ is explicitly mentioned. However, you're interested in what happens after the closing $$.
Reading the third double dangerous paragraph from the bottom, it's implicit that TeX is in vertical mode after it has processed the closing $$, because it has to insert vertical penalties and glue. Hence space tokens are ignored by rule.

The final task is to append the glue or the
equation number that follows the display. If there was an \eqno and if
e = 0, an infinite penalty is placed on the vertical list, followed by the
equation number box a shifted right by s + z minus its width, followed
by a penalty item whose cost is the value of \postdisplaypenalty.
Otherwise a penalty item for the \postdisplaypenalty is appended
first, followed by a glue item for gb as specified above. TeX now
adds 3 to \prevgraf and returns to horizontal mode, ready to resume the
paragraph.

The last sentence should solve the matter, I believe: space tokens never trigger horizontal mode.

I read that in the texbook just now and decided it didn't really answer. TeX returns to hmode on its own (as it says) but if it did that by implicitly inserting \noindent then a space token would make a space, if it did it by staying in vmode and waiting for the next character to trigger hmode space would be ignored but you'd get an indent.  It's actualy a custom processing not quite either of those things, unless I miss something?

@DavidCarlisle Since when is Knuth delivering the full truth?

well exactly so the correct answer to the question asked is, "this is only stated in the answer that you quote" not  the answer you give here which is "see page 188"

@DavidCarlisle That was also my first reaction. Knuth doesn't say that the indentation box is not inserted, but that's what everybody wants, isn't it?

But it's not in vmode waiting for something to start an unindented paragraph as you imply here, it's in hmode and gobbes an optional space (I posted a tex.web answer)
